# Transformation List of Lists with Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I have one JSON like this:

```json
{
  "item1": [
    "serv1",
    "serv2",
    "serv3"
  ],
  "item2": [
    {
      "obj": [
        "matriz1",
        "matriz2",
        "matriz3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "obj": [
        "matriz4",
        "matriz5",
        "matriz6"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I need to obtain this output:

```json
{
  "item1": [
    "serv1",
    "serv2",
    "serv3"
  ],
  "item2": [
    [
      "matriz1",
      "matriz2",
      "matriz3"
    ],
    [
      "matriz4",
      "matriz5",
      "matriz6"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I'm trying with this JOLT spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "item1": "item1",
      "item2": {
        "*": {
          "obj": "item2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But the output contains 3 elements of the first array, and then the second array like I want.

```json
{
  "item1": [
    "serv1",
    "serv2",
    "serv3"
  ],
  "item2": [
    "matriz1",
    "matriz2",
    "matriz3",
    [
      "matriz4",
      "matriz5",
      "matriz6"
    ]
  ]
}
```

What could be the correct JOLT spec to obtain the correct output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a shift transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "item1": "&",
      "item2": {
        "*": {
          "obj": "&2[&1]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where no need to repeat the key names, rather use substitutions through use of ampersands.

- **`&`** replaces current key names
- **`&2`** replaces **`"item2"`**, since needed to go 2 levels up to grab the name
- **`&2[&1]`** represents elements of the **`obj`** list nested within the key name **`"item2"`**

the ***demo*** on the site **http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/** is :

[image]